# How to get the URL query string in the getStaticProps export function on-page in next js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

http://localhost:3000/pages/testing?Afikim

```
export async function getStaticProps(){

    const  product = await repository.getProductAll("Afikim");

    
     return { props: {product} };
}
```

Comment: You can't retrieve query params added at request time from `getStaticProps` as it runs on the server at build time. You can access the query string on the client-side instead.

Comment: Thanks but any way to pass dynamic I'd in  getstaticprops.